# No Sound on Ubuntu 16.04 (Dummy Output)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have just got this computer and on the second day, i plugged my headphones and went to YouTube to watch some tutorials (Linux is so hard x.x).
After a few vids, the sound simply stopped working.
So I googled what it could be and i tried EVERYTHING online.
I tried the pulseaudio, force reload, etc...
My computer still does not recognize ANY audio cards.
Do you have any ideas on how i can solve this prob?

It is a Dell Inspiron 15 5000

Answer (score 0):

I found that a kernel update killed my sound on Ubuntu 16.04 and Dell XPS. I tried everything, including a BIOS update from Dell, but it was only temporary.  I received a new kernel update today (Linux 4.4.0.130), which seems to have fixed the problem.